# Фоновая работа в Android, постояное отслеживание координат

Tags: java, android

У меня есть такой вопрос: в приложении мне нужно постоянно мониторить координаты пользователей, при этом если они заходят в определенные локации то отсылать данные на сервер.

Для фоновой работы сейчас используется Sevice, но в последних версиях Android на работу сервисов наложен ряд ограничений, пробовал использовать Worker, но он запускается раз в 15 минут, а мне нужно чтобы фоновая работа не прерывалась.

**Вопрос:** что в данном случае предпочтительно использовать для непрерывной фоновой работы, которая должна запускаться после перезагрузки устройства и желательно без нотификаций.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: _запускаться после перезагрузки устройства и желательно без нотификаций_ - имхо - не хотелось бы что бы такого рода приложения работали без моего ведома, так что система поступает правильно завершая работу таких сервисов, либо пусть работают "прозрачно" с нотификацией, либо не работают вообще.

Comment: это служебное приложение, которое никогда не будет в Google Play и будет установлено на несколько девайсов